# InternetCheckConnection returns true after one successful test

Tags: wpf, connection, return, network-monitoring

Platform: ***WPF (.NET 4.5)***.

In order to check Internet connection as fast as it's possible I use this function:

```cs
    [DllImport("wininet.dll")]
    public extern static bool InternetCheckConnection(string lpszUrl, int dwFlags, int dwReserved);
```

The problem is that if I'm connected to the Internet and my program is executing `InternetCheckConnection`, it returns **true** (as expected) *BUT* if than I sleep the program for a moment and during this moment I disconnect my computer from the Internet and after that I check connection once again, than I have still **true** returned!

Why?!

I've prepared code that presents the problem:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace InternetCheckConnectionTest
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("wininet.dll")]
        public extern static bool InternetCheckConnection(string lpszUrl, int dwFlags, int dwReserved);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string www = "http://www.google.com/";

            Console.WriteLine("Checking connection...");
            bool connected = InternetCheckConnection(www, 1, 0);

            Console.WriteLine("Connection check returned " + connected.ToString());

            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
            Console.WriteLine("\nYou have " + ts.TotalSeconds.ToString() + " seconds to (dis)connect from/to the Internet.\n");
            Thread.Sleep(ts);

            Console.WriteLine("Checking connection once again...");
            connected = InternetCheckConnection(www, 1, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Connection (2nd) check returned " + connected.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Before starting this program make sure that you are connected to the Internet. 
After this message:

> You have 20 seconds to (dis)connect from/to the Internet.

disconnect from the Internet. You'll see that `InternetCheckConnection(www, 1, 0)` returns **True** even if you are disconnected from the Internet. The question is *why*?

Comment: What are you passing as your `dwFlags` parameter?

Comment: `dwFlags` = 1, `dwReserved` = 0

Comment: Try System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()

Comment: I need to check connection with specified URL.

Comment: It works for me (tested using wi-fi connection). How do you test it?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010. *CTRL + F5*. After first *true* I disconnect from my WiFi (icon in *Windows 7* tray) and wait for second *true*.

Comment: Maybe because you are asking twice? (1 returns true, 0 false, but only taking into account the first)

Comment: Try to disconnect the router's cable, if this works it means that your tray icon's disconnect command isn't working properly